# Detect after auto loading all selected elment from select2 of multiple type in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

**Problem Scenario** : I am using select2 of multiple type.ng-change is calling function `abc()` and update another value say `Y=10` another function update it and now it is `Y=8`. At the time of update all value auto populated and value of `Y=8` comes. But due to slow ng-change calls function `abc()` and it becomes `Y=10`.

Currently handling like this :

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.Y = data.Y;//which is 8 from DB
}, 2000);
```

**My Question** : How to detect that all element of select2 of multiple type is loaded so that I will update variable `$scope.Y` after that. I dont want to use `$timeout`.

Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you had a more complete example or a fiddle, that would be helpful

Comment: Could you please add actual code or sample code (if actual code is too long) to understand the problem clearly.

Comment: cant understand your problem please provide a plunkr thank you and if the problem is with loading data from multiple http requests you could use deferred promises refer this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine `$scope.$watch` would be the appropriate asynchronous check (vs `$timeout`).  `$scope.$watch('property-or-function-to-check', function(newVal, prevValue) {`.